# Functorial approach to Ideals and Quotients, Multiplicative Sets and Localizations

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, category-theory, ideals, universal-algebra

I have been playing with substructures of commutative rings today and noticed that there is a strong analogy between the formation of quotients and kernels with the formation of localizations with multiplicative sets. More precisely, given a commutative ring $R$, the ideal structure Ideal($R$) has a lattice structure (intersection and sums being the meet and join). Also the set of multiplicative submonoids of $R$, Mult($R$), also has a lattice structure (intersection and multiplicative closure being the meet and join). It can be verified that the following are functors,
$$
K\colon R\downarrow CRing\to Ideal(R),\ (f\colon R\to S)\mapsto ker(f)\\
Q\colon Ideal(R)\to R\downarrow CRing,\ I\mapsto (\pi_I\colon R\to R/I)
$$
with $\pi_I$ being the canonical projection. It can also be easily verified that $Q\dashv K$, i.e., formation of quotients is left adjoint to the formation of kernels. The counit of this adjunction is the well-known isomorphism theorem for rings. The unit is just the identity.

Similarly, if we denote the group of units of a ring $S$ by $S^*$, we can verify that the following are functorial as well,
$$
   L\colon R\downarrow CRing \to Mult(R),\ (f\colon R\to S)\mapsto f^{-1}(S^*)\\
   M\colon Mult(R)\to R\downarrow CRing,\ S\mapsto (\ell_S\colon R\to S^{-1}R)
$$
with $\ell_S$ being the canonical map $r\mapsto \frac{r}{1}$. Again, we can show $L\dashv M$, i.e., the formation of localizations is left adjoint to the formation of multiplicative sets. The counit of this adjunction is the universal mapping property of localizations. The unit being 
$$\eta_S\colon S\hookrightarrow ML(S)=\begin{cases}S\vee R^*& 0\not\in S\\ R& 0\in S \end{cases}.$$

(NOTE: Since $1=0$ in the zero ring, we are allowing $0$ to be a unit in the zero ring.)

> My question: Is there something deeper happening here? Are the constructions above particular instances of congruences on slice categories? Or can we generalize to other algebraic structures, i.e., in a universal algebraic sense?

Comment: You can view $R / CRing$ as a variety of universal algebra (take the ring axioms and add in a new constant for each element of $R$ and a new axiom for each arithmetic equation about elements of $R$). I'm not sure if this connects to the other categories you're looking at.

Comment: In both cases, you have a dual lattice: the lattice of quotients of $R$ and the lattice of localizations of $R$, both subcategories of $R / CRing$. It may be more fruitful to think in terms of that.

Comment: I don't really understand the question. What do you want to know?

Comment: @Hurkyl Thanks. That's a good point. Since the unit is iso in the formation of quotients, the lattice structure embeds in $R\downarrow CRing$. I also thought it interesting how the universal properties of quotients and localization are evident in the counits.

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan I dont have much experience with category theory, so I am wondering if for example given an algebra (in the universal sense), if there are general substructures of it (which may constitute modular lattices) which give rise to similar adjoint pairs. Or is CRing a special case? Sorry for the vagueness...

Comment: You are just rephrasing the usual universal properties in terms of an adjunction, which is always possible. Nothing deep here, really.

Comment: Thanks. If you have a universal property, doesn't framing considerations of adjunctions give us something for free, such as preservation of limits/colimits for right/left adjoints. Or do you think such rephrasing is overdoing it?

Comment: @Rachmaninoff, its not overdoing it, in fact this is a very nice way of describing what's going on.